# How return to savedposition in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have this problem that i have a `ListView` and when you click on item it opens another `Activity` with some information, then when I go back scroll is in right position (because I have `setselection(savedPosition)` in `onResume`), but then after one second it goes back again on top.
Please help.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Book>>{

private String URL;
int positionScroll;

List<Book> books;

ListView booksListView = null;



private static final int BOOK_ID = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_RESPONSE = 1;
int clickCounter = 0;

private BooksAdapter adapter;
private TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
    final LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textSearch);
    final String[] textEdit = new String[1];
    // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
    booksListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bookList);
    booksListView.setSelection(positionScroll);
    adapter = new BooksAdapter(this,new ArrayList<Book>());



    textView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    booksListView.setEmptyView(textView);


    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);



    booksListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_ID, null, MainActivity.this);


    textView.setText("");
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            textView.setText("");
            adapter.clear();
            booksListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            clickCounter++;
            hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
            editText.clearFocus();


            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
            // so the list can be populated in the user interface
            booksListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            textEdit[0] = editText.getText().toString();
            URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + textEdit[0] + "&maxResults=40&printType=books&startIndex=0";
            if (mWifi.isConnected()) {

                // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
                // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid                    // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
                loaderManager.restartLoader(BOOK_ID, null, MainActivity.this);
            }else{
                //ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                textView.setText("No internet connection.");
            }


        }
    });
    booksListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            booksListView.setSelection(positionScroll);
        }
    });





}


@Override
public Loader<List<Book>> onCreateLoader(int i,Bundle args) {
    return new BookLoader(this,URL,books);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Book>> loader, final List<Book> books) {
    adapter.clear();
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // If there is a valid list of {@link Book}s, then add them to the adapter's
    // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
    if (books != null && !books.isEmpty()) {
        adapter.refreshEvents(books);

        booksListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                positionScroll = position;

                Log.e(MainActivity.class.getName(),"Book: " + books);
                Intent x = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BookActivity.class);
                x.putExtra("My class",books.get(position));
                startActivityForResult(x,REQUEST_RESPONSE);
            }
        });
    }
    textView.setText("No books found.");

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Book>> loader) {
    adapter.clear();
}
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    booksListView.setSelection(positionScroll);
  }
}
```

Comment: You must use saveInstanceState to save the state of listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Save the ListView state (= includes scroll position) as a Parceble
 Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();  

// Restore previous state (including selected item index and scroll position)
listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state); 

// Save the ListView state (= includes scroll position) as a Parceble
Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();

// e.g. set new items
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

// Restore previous state (including selected item index and scroll position)
listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
```